# Cakephp 3 newEntity() not working

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, nginx

I have to maintenance the **cakephp 3** project and in this project, they have create `newEntity` using array variable and then data are not save into database. I set `print_r` to get result of `userModel` but it doesn't show anything.

I was using **nginx** server (not apache), **mysql 5.6**, **cakephp 3**.

Here is the code what they used.

```
 $userModel = $this->newEntity($tableData);
        print_r($userModel);
        if (!$userModel->errors()) {

            $result = $this->save($userModel);
            if ($result)
            {
                return $result->id;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: can you check $this ?

Comment: Try `var_dum($userModel); die();` to print out the information in the `$userModel`. Where this code is situated ? in the Controller ?

Comment: Yes. It's in Controller. Bro Mehdi Bouzidi

Comment: I tried as you said var_dum($userModel); die(); but nothing show up.. The codes below  $userModel = $this->newEntity($tableData);  are not working and the codes above  $userModel = $this->newEntity($tableData); are all working. :(

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to check first.

1. Try outputting the $tableData variable and ensuring the elements in it match up against the data structure you have for the model object you're trying to create.
2. To manipulate the entity. You should be calling it using
   $this->ModelName->newEntity($tableData);
   $this->ModelName->save($userModel)

Answer (score 0):

You need call the model name to generate a new entity and to save it.

If your model name are $tableData:

```
Replace your $this->newEntity($tableData) to $this->$tableData->newEntity();

and your $this->save($userModel) to $this->$tableData->save($userModel);
```